# How Can I Pause & Resume When My Token Needs to Be Refreshed?

Tags: node.js

I am posting a large amount of data to an API that uses a token that needs to be refreshed every 30 minutes.

How would I pause my script when the token expires, refresh the token and then resume from when we left off?

I have so far:

```
const post = await mergedItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const postBody = `{ "ItemShops": { "ItemShop": [{ "itemShopID": ${item.itemShopID}, "qoh": ${item.qoh} }]}}`
      setTimeout(() => {
      axios({
        url: `${lightspeedApi}/Account/${accountID}/Item/${item.id}.json`,
        method: 'put',
        headers: authHeader,
        data: postBody
      }).then(response => {
        if (response.status == 401) {
          refreshToken()
        } else {
        console.log(response.data) }
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
    }, index * 10000)
    })
  })
}}
```

Comment: You can't just pause things, your forEach (note that there's no point awaiting it or returning from the callback) has started multiple parallel promises. I'd expect what you'll see one the token expires is multiple attempts to refresh the token, also in parallel. You have a similar problem to https://instagram-engineering.com/thundering-herds-promises-82191c8af57d

Comment: So the best solution may be to cache the token and then keep the token up to date in cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a common problem, and parallels (ha!) that described [here](https://instagram-engineering.com/thundering-herds-promises-82191c8af57d). You're starting multiple requests in parallel, and can expect that as soon as one receives a 401 response the others will get the same shortly thereafter. This means they all start to try to refresh the token, *also* in parallel.

A rough sketch of how to apply the solution follows:

```js
const makeRequest = async (opts) => {
  try {
    return axios(opts);
  catch (err) {
    // note axios throws on >=400 response code, not like fetch
    if (err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
      await refreshToken();
      return makeRequest(opts);
    else {
      raise err;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can expose a promise of the token getting refreshed, and reuse it to avoid making multiple requests while one is already in-flight:

```js
let refreshPromise;

export const refreshToken = () => {
  if (!refreshPromise) {
    // start a refresh request only if one isn't in flight
    refreshPromise = axios(...).then((res) => {
      // ... reset token
      refreshPromise = null;
    });
  }
  return refreshPromise; 
};
```

Comment: Thank you for delving into this, it's a great help. I've got some reading to do :).

Comment: @jonrsharpe but is it possible to do:  You're starting multiple requests in parallel, and as soon as one receives a 401 response the others will intantly await refreshToken(); and NOT SEND the request (which would receive a 401 response anyways if it was sent without refreshing token) ?
Your answer is the only one that I've found so far solving at least refresh avalanche problem so thank you soo much!