# Singleton service in Angular with async HTTP call?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, async-await, singleton

I am developing a web application using Angular (2+) and I need to implement a service like this:
I have an endpoint (URL) and I use this URL to do a POST HTTP call. The response contains a **token** and a **number of seconds** indicating how long this token is valid.
My service has to do this thing: check if the token has expired (i.e. if the deadline has passed). If yes, it makes the HTTP call and gets a new token, if not, it returns the previously stored token to the client.

This is my code example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyPOSTService {

  private deadline;
  private token; // Stringa in cui viene salvato il tokenSTS  temporaneo

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async getToken() {

    if(!this.deadline || Math.ceil(new Date().getTime()) > this.deadline) {
            
      await this.http.post(MY_URL, MY_BODY).toPromise().then((data: any) => {
      
        if(data) {
          this.token = data.token;
          this.deadline = data.deadline + Math.ceil(new Date().getTime()/60000) - 1;
        }
      })
    }

    return this.token;
  }

}
```

where `MY_URL` is the endpoint and `MY_BODY` is the request body. `data.token` is the token and `data.deadline` is the **number of seconds** indicating how long this token is valid.
Unfortunately **this solution doesn't work**. If a client calls the `getToken()` method multiple times after some time, due to the asynchronous call, `this.deadline` will always be undefined!
How do I make the call in synchronous way? So that the `getToken()` method becomes "atomically callable"?

Surely I am wrong approach but I hope I have been clear. How do I implement what I would like to achieve? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First thing (may not be related to question): Using promises and async/await is a bad start. You should try to use Observables the way they work.

Comment: My application code is actually different. I don't use HttpClient but the HTTP call is wrapped in a proprietary library that uses Observables. However, the question remains unchanged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Pause & Resume When My Token Needs to Be Refreshed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594996/how-can-i-pause-resume-when-my-token-needs-to-be-refreshed)

Comment: That shows a promise-based approach, but given Angular is based on RxJS you could use the same ideas in an observable-based approach.

Comment: I just want a suggestion on how I can go about achieving my purpose (singleton with synchronous call). Can you give some code examples?